# CSS Animation on Mouse Down

Tags: css

i created a css class for animation on click a div

```
.part{
  &:active{
    animation: bounce 0.7s 1 linear;
  }
}


@keyframes bounce {
50% {
  transform: rotate(5deg) translate(20px, -50px);
}
to {
  transform: scale(0.9) rotate(10deg) translate(50px, -280px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

}

```
 <a href="[{$_productLink}]" class="" title="Bag">
      <div class="part">
         <i class="fas fa-shopping-bag"></i>
      </div>
 </a>
```

when i click the div, the animations starts for 0.1 sek, only when i hold the mouse button, i can see the full animation, any idea how i can fix this? I want to see the full animation on mouse down.

Comment: This is because you are applying animation only during `:active` state

Comment: And how i can start the animation on click state?

Comment: share the full code so we can see what are you trying to achieve

Comment: i added the html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added runnable code snippet with comments as per your requirements.

```js
document.querySelector('.part').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.add('animate')
  
  /*
  You can skip below code. 
  As it removes animate class once animation is done.
  */
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.classList.remove('animate')
  }, 3000)
})
```

```css
/*Added animate class so which can be added later to div to animate it when it is clicked*/
.part i {
font-size: 40px
}
.part.animate{
    animation: bounce 0.7s linear;
}


@keyframes bounce {
50% {
  transform: rotate(5deg) translate(20px, -50px);
}
to {
  transform: scale(0.9) rotate(10deg) translate(50px, -280px);
  opacity: 0;
}
}
```

```html
 <a href="#!" class="" title="Bag">
      <div class="part">
         <i class="fas fa-shopping-bag"></i>
      </div>
    </a>
```

Comment: Thanks that work for me, but only for the first div, i had more then one div with class part. is this also possible?

Comment: Yeah just toggle that animate class for other divs

Comment: Sure:)How can i toogle that animate class for the other divs?

Comment: Select all divs using querySelectorAll() and then listen to click events on those divs and do the same logic inside it that I mentioned above